Не могу запустить ОС после разделения жесткого диска
После уменьшения раздела на жестком диске не могу загрузиться ни с флешки с установщиком windows, ни в установленную ранее ubuntu, на экране после загрузки вылезает терминал grub, изменение порядка загрузки в биосе не помогает. Можно ли полностью сбросить ноут к заводским через grub?

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/REFInd не помог?

Если вы попадаете в grub rescue с ошибкой error:unknown filesystem, то примеров выхода из подобной ситуации полно. Вот здесь и здесь подробно описано. От себя могу посоветовать загрузиться с Live CD/USB (если такая возможность есть) в Ubuntu и попробовать исправить ситуацию с помощью boot-repair:
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -y boot-repair
boot-repair

После запуска просто выберите Recommended repair.
Можете так же посмотреть, что у вас по состоянию файловой системы:
sudo fsck /dev/sda

Только замените /dev/sda на физический том (диск, проще говоря), к которому у вас примонтирован / (корневая директория). Как правило, по дефолту это /dev/sda, но я же не знаю, как у вас ОС настроена. Проверить данные по примонтированным директориям можно командой lsblk.
Еще можете вручную попробовать восстановить grub с помощью chroot, но это уже на ваш страх и риск ;)
sudo mount /dev/sda /mnt # /dev/sda замените на расположение вашей корневой директории
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
sudo chroot /mnt
update-grub
grub-install /dev/sda  # замените /dev/sda на ваш жесткий диск, если надо
exit
sudo umount /mnt/dev
sudo umount /mnt/proc
sudo umount /mnt/sys
sudo umount /mnt

